# Jenkins 2.x Slave-Agent Variables in Pipelines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have tried every permutation that I can find to pull a pre-existing variable from a specific Jenkins Slave and I cannot find a solution.

We have a git branch variable defined on each slave agent as a default branch for all builds initiated on that slave.  This is to ensure that all DSL scripted job config is tested on our dev machine before it is promoted to a higher jenkins environment.

I have created a pipeline that will build all the components needed to stand up a new jenkins (with all of our enterprise deployment pipelines created) and it needs access to that one specific variable to correctly build the jobs based on the jenkins master/slave combo that it is running on.

I need a way (in a jenkinsfile) to access the variables that are configured on a particular jenkins slave machine.

[image: Jenkins node configuration]

Comment: Dis you try so simply use the env object? Inside of a node block for each machine, of course.

Comment: I have tried to use several different interations of the env object.  I have tried using it at a global level outside the node.  Also, I tried inside the node object and none of them seemed to return the node parameter value that I had set.  Sometimes I would get a null object and other times I would get an empty string value returned.  i will update once I experiment some more.

Comment: I want to leave a note to save some time of those who stumble over this question.

This is a reported and until today(March 2020) still unreasolved Jenkins bug.

You may check the resolution status by following this link: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44425 https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44465

If the bug is fixed, but you are facing this issue, please ignore this answer.